# Failure to install NetFX3 on Windows Server 2012: Error 3017 -- Am I missing something here?

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net-3.5

I am really struggling to get this installed. I have tried the suggestions [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) in an attempt to rectify any possible corruption. I mounted the disk image to 'G' to do an offline install. I also attempted an online install with similar results. Output as follows:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /So
urce:G:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Image Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 3017

The requested operation failed. A system reboot is required to roll back changes
 made.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Log as follows (Errors/Warnings Only):

```
2013-04-08 23:40:17, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x80070bc9)
2013-04-08 23:40:17, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x80070bc9)
2013-04-08 23:40:17, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed ProcessChanges. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x80070bc9)
2013-04-08 23:40:17, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070bc9)
2013-04-08 23:40:17, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80070BC9
2013-04-08 23:38:10, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3160 TID=3172 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Windows\TEMP\505F54F1-4977-4233-835C-8B6DA83BCAEB\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2013-04-08 23:39:23, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\F1B7A223-F380-4F42-84BF-396D374EE80B\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2013-04-08 23:39:23, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\F1B7A223-F380-4F42-84BF-396D374EE80B\IBSProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
2013-04-08 23:39:23, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed to get the IDismObject Interface - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_LoadProvider(hr:0x80004002)
2013-04-08 23:39:23, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\F1B7A223-F380-4F42-84BF-396D374EE80B\Wow64provider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x80004002)
2013-04-08 23:39:23, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=3756 TID=3768 Failed to Load the provider: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\F1B7A223-F380-4F42-84BF-396D374EE80B\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
```

None of my error codes align with any of those on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782/en-us) MS support page.
I would really appreciate your assistance. I am really struggling with a solution. Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT:**
I have verified the checksum of my ISO image:

File Name: en_windows_server_2012_x64_dvd_915478.iso

SHA1: D09E752B1EE480BC7E93DFA7D5C3A9B8AAC477BA

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try without LimitAccess?  Please check the source. You could
  copy to a local drive and try again.
- Turn off the feature via the control panel and try again.
- Also check with network connection and no network connection.
- 0x8007007e means module not found. In that case you could use a downloaded package.
- Clean all the temp files before you begin. Check permissions as well.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Turn off the feature via control panel...". I'm trying to install a feature (NetFX3).

Comment: Please read this carefully: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831809.aspx#BKMK_FoD

Comment: I still don't understand please be more specific. The feature is not currently on because it fails to install. As you can see from the information in my original post I am using the DISM method that's outlined in the technet article. I also tried the "Add Roles and Features" wizard specifying the sxs path. This is why i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall the following security updates and then try again to install framework 3.5. Uninstall the following security updates:

1. 2966827
2. 2966828
3. 2966826

After these steps you should be able to install framework 3.5 . Make sure, that you install the latest updates after you had installed the framework 3.5 so you have no security leaks.

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002547) is the link for more information about the problem.